# Как правильно записать ф-цию malloc на Си?

Tags: c, malloc

Нужно создать массив с помощью `malloc`. Как я прочитал есть два способа записи этой функции:

```
    int * buffer = malloc (i * sizeof (int));
```

и

```
    int *buffer = (int *) malloc (i);
```

Но, когда я пытаюсь очистить выделенную память после того как использовал вторую запись, то программа вылетает. В остальном же никакой разницы не заметил. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Что вы сделали не так? Не привели минимального примера для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: и что мне еще сдесь добавить? Дописать ф-цию main? Сдесь всего две строчки: выделение и освобождение памяти - вылетает при втором типе записи, когда пытаюсь освободить память.

Comment: Может вы ее очищаете неправильно или используете. Я всегда пишу как во втором варианте и у меня все работает.

Comment: `(int*)` дополнительную память не выделяет. И [вообще не нужно здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/4279). Если предположить, что первый фрагмент правильное количество памяти выделяет, то второй фрагмент выделяет её у вас недостаточно, что к segfault при дальнейшем использовании может вести. Для ясности приведите полный (но минимальный) пример (к примеру, покажите как на ideone.com падает или хотя бы явно опции компилятора упомяните).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Во-первых, ваши два способа почти никак между собой не связаны: в первом фигурирует `sizeof(int)`, а во втором его не видно. Поэтому не понятно, прочему вы их вообще привели вместе.

  Также, в соответствии с такой логикой составления "способов", не составит труда придумать еще пятьдесят два "способа записи этой функции", поэтому не ясно, почему ваш источник утверждает, что их всего два.
- Во-вторых, явное приведение типа возвращаемого значения `malloc` (как во втором способе) - ненужная, бессмысленная и вредная практика. (см. также DRY ниже)
- В-третьих, для выделения памяти под массив через `malloc` существует прекрасная идиома, построенная в соответствии с принципом [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself)

  ```
  int *buffer = malloc(i * sizeof *buffer);
  // Полагая, что `i` - требуемый размер массива
  ```

  Обратите внимание, что конкретное имя типа в этом варианте упоминается только один-единственный раз - в объявлении переменной. Именно (и только) в объявлениях и должны упоминаться конкретные типы. Остальной код, за пределами объявлений, в идеале, должен быть типонезависим (type-agnostic), т.е. не содержать никаких упоминаний имен типов вообще. Это не всегда достижимо, но в случае выделения памяти через `malloc` это вполне возможно.

Answer (score 3):

Вы выделили слишком мало памяти. При работе вы вышли за границы выделенной памяти, затерли служебную информацию диспетчера памяти и при освобождении памяти произошли неприятности...

`malloc` выделяет указанное количество **байт**, так что если вам нужна память для `N` целых чисел - то выделяйте `malloc(N*sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Если я вышел за границы массива, то почему, в таком случае при первой записи программа не вылетает? А вылетает только если запись второго рода.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в первом случае вы выделили память для `i` элементов по четыре байта каждый (итоговый занимаемый размер получаем перемножением этих двух чисел). Во втором случае вы выделили просто `i` байт, то есть в четыре раза меньше. Не забывайте, что `malloc()` ничего не знает о типе хранимого значения, он просто выделяет непрерывный регион памяти длиной в указанное количество байт, а как вы потом будете работать с полученным побайтовым указателем — не её дело.

Comment: Читаем еще раз начало второго абзаца ответа... *malloc выделяет указанное количество* **байт**. `sizeof(int)` - никак не единица...

Comment: тобишь вообще не важно: писать (int *) перед malloc или не писать, все равно выделит только указанное количество байт?

Comment: Если вы действительно пишете на C, а не просто указали такой тэг - то `(int*)` можно вообще не писать. И да, это *приведение типа* никак не влияет на работу `malloc()`.

Comment: Вроде бы приведение типа иногда может повлиять на работу malloc, а точнее вызвать ошибки, кажется это связано с тем что при этом  компилятор может выполнить выравнивание.